# Reason for using 'does' in 'Than does that of'

Tags: sentence-construction

'The structure of non-finite subordinate clauses differs more radically from that of main clauses than **does** that of finite subordinate clauses.'

```
 - A student's introduction to English
    Grammar by Huddleston
```

Why 'does' is used after 'than'. It is used to follow any grammatical rule?

Comment: Just as your text includes the relative pronoun ***that*** (the first instance, after ***from***), which refers back to the previously-specified noun ***structure***, so ***does*** refers back to the previously-specified verb ***differs***. One of the "rules" ***does*** follows here is that it's inflected the same as the "original" verb it's echoing. So your text could be rephrased with a plural subject as *The **structures** of non-finite subordinate clauses **differ** more radically from that of main clauses than **do** that of finite subordinate clauses*.

Comment: The structure of non-finite subordinate clauses differs more radically from [the structure] of main clauses than does [the structure] of finite subordinate clauses [differ].

Comment: A better question is why Huddleston is using such obtuse structure in a student's intro to English book.

Answer (score 1):

*Does* is used here to avoid ambiguity.

> A differs more from B than C.

is ambiguous as to where it is comparing the difference between A and B with the difference between A and C or the difference between C and B.

> A differs more from B than C does

makes it clear that it is the difference between C and B which is the second term in the comparison.

In the example you quote, *does* comes before the object phrase "that of finite subordinate clauses" because of [heavy clause extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition): *than that of finite subordinate clauses does* would be grammatical, but rather less clear.

Answer (score 1):

'The structure of non-finite subordinate clauses differs more radically from that of main clauses than does that of finite subordinate clauses.'

- Main clauses have one structure;
- Finite subordinate clauses have a second structure, one that differs mildly from the first structure;
- And non-finite subordinate clauses have a third structure, one that
  differs radically from the first structure.

So, the third structure differs from the first more than the second structure ***does***. The use of ***does*** seems normal to me, as in the more ordinary statement "I like apples more than my brother ***does***."